# SQL- Pivot and aggregation

Tags: sql-server

Hi I am trying to pivot a table that looks like this:

[image]

However I keep getting invalid column name error for placement_name. This is for SQL Server

```
Select PLACEMENT_NAME, 'MALE 18-20','MALE 13-17'
      FROM
      (SELECT PLACEMENT_NAME, DEMO_NAME
       FROM myTable) up
      pivot
      (max(placement_name) for DEMO_NAME in (['MALE 18-20'], ['MALE 13-17'])
      )AS pvt;
```

Comment: `a table that looks like this` ... I can't really see what the table looks like.  Can you please include your table as _text_, not a shrunken image?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

Single Quotes `'male'`are for strings, you need `[]` to indicate fieldName

```
Select PLACEMENT_NAME, [MALE 18-20], [MALE 13-17]
....
.... for DEMO_NAME in ([MALE 18-20], [MALE 13-17])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Select PLACEMENT_NAME, [MALE 18-20],[MALE 13-17]
      FROM
      (SELECT PLACEMENT_NAME, DEMO_NAME
       FROM myTable) up
      pivot
      (max(placement_name) for DEMO_NAME in ([MALE 18-20], [MALE 13-17])
      )AS pvt;
```